# How to color edges in igraph depending on their start and end vertices?

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I have been struggling with igraph and do not seem to find documentation that provides me with the results that I need.

I have an igraph object, let's say g1, which consists in a network obtained from an adjacency matrix. I know that i need to apply the E function to get all edges, and for example when I apply E(g1)[1] I get (variables have been anonymized for the example):

- 1/1132 edge from 4cab94f (vertex names):
  [1] Var1--Var2

I would like to get the vertex indexes, and I have found that if I look at the first element in the list above I get

> E(g1)[1][[1]]

- 1/1132 edge from 4cab94f (vertex names):
  tail    head tid hid color
  1    Var1    Var2   1 109 black

**I want to have access to the "tid" and "hid" values. **I know that it's probably a stupid question but I have tried many commands and can't seem to understand what type of object is

> E(g1)[1][[1]].

**The reason for this is that, to show some expected relationships in my dataset, I want to parse my edge list and change the colors of those for which hid = tid+108 to red and using these objects seems to be the quickest/easiest way to do it.**

Comment: Hi etomilina, welcome to SO. It will make it much easier to answer your question if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121). So run `dput()` on the data you are using e.g. `dput(g1)` or `dput(head(g1),n)`  if your dataset is large where n is the minimum number of rows needed to demonstrate your issue. Then, copy the result into a codeblock in your question. Also include the code you are using and the associated libraries. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to convert the graph's edge list to a data frame, and use R base calculations to find the needed edges.

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(2024)
g <- sample_gnp(10, 6/10)     # Graph to test (undirected).

df1 <- as_edgelist(g)         # Edgelist to dataframe.

# Edge (eid) / Vertex ids. are sequentially numbered starting with 1.
# Diff is the difference between vertex ids of edge tail and edge head. 
df2 <- cbind(eid = seq_len(gsize(g)), hid=df1[,1], tid=df1[,2],  diff = df1[, 2] - df1[, 1] )


ids <- abs(df2[, "diff"])== 3 # Calculate rows with given row condition (TRUE or FALSE).
red <- which(ids)             # Compute the row ids that satisfies the given condition.
E(g)[red]
# + 4/28 edges from 6177b53:
# [1] 2--5 3--6 5--8 6--9

E(g)$color      <- "black"    # Default color.
E(g)[red]$color <- "red"      # Set color.
plot(g)                       # Show plot.

# show frequency distribution.
table(df2[,"diff"])
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
# 7 8 4 1 5 1 1 1

dev.new(); hist(df2[,"diff"], breaks=gsize(g))
```

**Added, approach without edge list**

```
red <- which(abs(tail_of(g, E(g)) - head_of(g, E(g)) ) == 3)
```

[image]